# Deep fryer oil guidelines

Tags: food-safety, deep-frying

Where can I find food safety guidelines on how to handle reusing deep fryer oil several times for a variety of different foods.
I imagine that oil used only for vegetables can be reused for longer (both safely and taste wise) vs oil used for items that contain dairy. That’s just one example.
I’m looking for the USA.

There is [this](https://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsis/topics/food-safety-education/get-answers/food-safety-fact-sheets/safe-food-handling/deep-fat-frying-and-food-safety/ct_index/!ut/p/a1/jZDbCsIwDIafxQcoyZwOvZSBuOk2RNTaGym23Qraja14enqr3qh4Sq6SfP-fEGBAgRm-1zm3ujR8e61ZsMYpBl4_xDjre0OM0sU0G4ch9mZdB6y-AKn_p_5DDPCXPv5jQbtOwiQHVnFbEG1UCTSXlnDTHGTdAFVlKUjDlbQnovjGkqaQ0rrBtUdu04IbsdUmByqkrBxliapPruFcBHkwALqxa22EPMIS2PNx6LmMUn_WGcWpj1nnFXjzvTvw-T3Vbk7Pk8EIddS6AKdgZaU!/#9) but it doesn’t address vegetable vs animal products not does it address reusing the oil several times.

Answer (score 1):

Serious eats has a good overview https://www.seriouseats.com/2013/09/ask-the-food-lab-how-many-times-can-i-reuse-fry-oil.html

There is not a "how many times" or "good for a number of days" answer because there are too many variables, but your linked article clearly spells out what to look for to know when to discard.

Working in a high volume kitchen, we filtered the oil in each fryer for three services, and discarded it after the fourth. The exception was if we cooked fish, the oil would be discarded following that service.